Nextjs @vercel/postgres gives VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string'
I am using @vercel/postgres for using database operations in a Nextjs project. When I try to fetch rows from the database I get no errors but when I try to insert a value It gives the following error:
VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.
I checked my .env file for any missing variables but they are all present. Here they is the list for reference (I have kept the values secret):
POSTGRES_URL="********"
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL=""********"
POSTGRES_URL_NO_SSL=""********"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING=""********"
POSTGRES_USER=""********"
POSTGRES_HOST=""********"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=""********"
POSTGRES_DATABASE=""********"

here is how I am trying to insert a row:
export const createColor = async (code: string) => {
        try {
            const query = `INSERT INTO colors(name, code) VALUES('(${code.replace(
                "#",
                ""
            )})', '${code}');`;
            const data =
                await sql`INSERT INTO colors(name, code) VALUES('(${code.replace(
                    "#",
                    ""
                )})', '${code}');`;
            console.log(data);

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
};

